# jQuery cycle pugin and infinite loop

Tags: jquery, plugins, loops, cycle

I'm using [THIS](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin to show "n" strings that scroll up every 5 seconds.

In particular you can see the example at the bottom [HERE](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html).

This plugin show just one element each time so I did this splitup function that show 7 element:

```
$.fn.splitUp = function (splitBy, wrapper) {
    $all = $(this).find('>*');
    var fragment = Math.ceil($all.length / splitBy);
    for (i = 0; i < fragment; i++)
        $all.slice(splitBy * i, splitBy * (i + 1)).wrapAll(wrapper);
    return $(this);
}

$('#list').splitUp(7, '<li><li/>').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollUp',
    pause: 1,
    timeout: 5000,
    speed: 2000
});
```

it works fine.

The problem is: if I have 9 strings it show the first 7 and than only 2 strings...
I'd like to show 7 strings and than 2 + 5. An infinite loop.

How can be possible to do that?

Thanks

**EDIT**
http://jsfiddle.net/QZu2Z/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of what you have, it'd be easier to work with.

Comment: I tried messing with this for a few but had no luck; I can tell you it should be able to be done and that you need to use the `before` event; with it is passed an options property object and with that object is an `addSlide()` method to dynamically add new slides to the slideshow while its running.  Take a look at this page http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23 in the middle of it are 3 demos labeled "Add slides to a running slideshow".  Basically you'll need to calculate which of your strings to show on the next slide and dynamically add them to the slideshow using `addSlide()`.

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/QZu2Z/2/ I did in a different way but with no luck regarding the loop, but it's an easyer way for sure... maybe you're lucker than me to solve it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `before` event and the `addSlide()` method available to the options property passed by the event.  I added comments to the code to explain what's going on.

**CODE** (Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QZu2Z/4/)

```
var pos = 0;
var count = 1;
var maxItems = 7;
var items = [];

function createSlide()
{
    // This function takes the array of items we have and builds a new ul
    // list based on maxitems and last pos, the result is multiple calls
    // to this function produces output like so:

    //  First pass returns: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    // Second pass returns: 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
    //  Third pass returns: 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
    //  Forth pass returns: 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
    // and so forth...

    var elem = $('<ul class="list"></ul>');

    for(i = 1; i <=9; i++)
    {
        if (pos >= 9)
        {
            pos = 0;
        }

        if(count <= maxItems)
        {
            count = count + 1;

            $(elem).append(items[pos]);

            pos = pos + 1;
        }
    }

    count = 1;

    return elem;
}

function onBefore(curr, next, opts) {
    // This is the onBefore slide event; we're simply checking if the addSlide
    // method is available on the opts object as apparently on the first pass,
    // addSlide is undefined (plugin hasn't yet created the function);

    if (!opts.addSlide)
    {
        return;
    }

    // addSlide function is available so generate the next slide and add it
    opts.addSlide(createSlide());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Generate an array of items to use in our cycle
    $(".wrapper li").each(function(i) {
        items[i] = $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    });

    // Grab the slideshow object
    var $ss = $('.wrapper');

    // Erase the contents, we have the data stored in the array [items]
    $ss.empty();

     // Create new slide and append it to our object, results in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    $ss.append(createSlide());

    // Create another slide and append it to our object, results 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
    $ss.append(createSlide());

    // start the slideshow (a slideshow can't be started unless there's 2 
    // slides hence why we created two slides above to start with).  The
    // before/onBefore event will add a new slide every cycle of the slideshow.
    $ss.cycle({
        fx: 'scrollUp',
        pause: 1,
        timeout: 5000,
        speed: 2000,
        before: onBefore
    });
});
```

***Extra Note:***

One thing to keep in mind although it shouldn't be a problem for most people is since this does add a new slide every cycle, having your browser open on the page for a long period of time will start to suck up more and more resources as new elements are constantly being added to the DOM.  There is however a fix too it figure out when you've looped through to cycle them back to original starting point then no new slides need to be added and it can loop them; visually this is easier to see then to explain

```
 -> createSlide() = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (store this first results to compare with rest)
|   createSlide() = 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
|   createSlide() = 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
|   createSlide() = 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
|   createSlide() = 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
|   createSlide() = 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
|   createSlide() = 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
|   createSlide() = 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
 -< createSlide() = 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    createSlide() = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (this value equals the first result so no new 
slides need to be added, let the process use the slides that are already added
and loop back to the beginning
```

***Extra Extra Note:***

Another thing I just realized is if you use the technique above then technically you can get rid of the `before` event callback and simply generate all the needed slides before you even start the slideshow.

Comment: I just added a new var, var listItems = $('.list li').length; to get dynamically the length of the list, replacing the "9" with listItems. It works, +1.

Comment: Glad we found a working solution, I just updated my answer with some more information that could be useful.